# tabu rowcolor multicolumns

Tags: multicol, tabu, colortbl

I try to put the background of the first line in color. I try like the commented line but I have a compiled errors. I try with `\tabuphantomline`. But I didn't succeeded.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{tikzsymbols}

\begin{document}
\taburowcolors[2] 2{black!15 .. black!30}
\begin{tabu}{|X[5,l]|X[1,c]|}
  \hline
  % \multicolumn2{|{>\rowcolor{red}}l|}{\textbf{Général}} \\  \hline
  \multicolumn2{|l|}{\textbf{Général}} \\  \hline
  1 & \dSadey[1.5][red] \\ \hline
  \multicolumn2{|l|}{\textbf{Miroir}} \\ \hline
  d0  & \dSmiley[1.5][green] \\ \hline
  d1  & \dSmiley[1.5][green] \\ \hline
  d3  & \dSmiley[1.5][green] \\ \hline
  d7  & \dSmiley[1.5][green] \\ \hline
  d10 & \dSmiley[1.5][green] \\ \hline
  \multicolumn2{|l|}{\textbf{Système de fichier}} \\ \hline
  /            & \dSmiley[1.5][green]    \\ \hline
  /var         & \dSmiley[1.5][green]    \\ \hline
  /var/run     & \dSmiley[1.5][green]    \\ \hline
  /tmp         & \dSmiley[1.5][green]    \\ \hline
\end{tabu}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Voici. Unrelated, but `frenchb` should be loaded with the documentclass, and replaced with the option `[french]`.

```
\documentclass[11pt, french]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikzsymbols}

\begin{document}

\taburowcolors[2] 2{black!15 .. black!30}
\begin{tabu}{|X[5,l]|X[1,c]|}
  \hline
 \multicolumn2{|>{\columncolor{red}}l|}{\textbf{Général}} \\ \hline
  1 & \dSadey[1.5][red] \\ \hline
  \multicolumn2{|l|}{\cellcolor{red}\textbf{Miroir}} \\ \hline
  d0 & \dSmiley[1.5][green] \\ \hline
  d1 & \dSmiley[1.5][green] \\ \hline
  d3 & \dSmiley[1.5][green] \\ \hline
  d7 & \dSmiley[1.5][green] \\ \hline
  d10 & \dSmiley[1.5][green] \\ \hline
  \multicolumn2{|l|}{\cellcolor{red}\textbf{Système de fichiers}} \\ \hline
  / & \dSmiley[1.5][green] \\ \hline
  /var & \dSmiley[1.5][green] \\ \hline
  /var/run & \dSmiley[1.5][green] \\ \hline
  /tmp & \dSmiley[1.5][green] \\ \hline
\end{tabu}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: But It doesn't work for the second multicolumn line :  \multicolumn2{|>{\columncolor{red}}l|}{\textbf{Système de fichier}} \\ \hline

Comment: You didn't ask it. Use `\cellcolor` (see the updated answer).